# Цикл в python помогите пожалуйста

Tags: python, алгоритм, циклы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите пожалуйста написать цикл `range` или `while`
Мое начало, дальше не знаю что делать..

```
n = int (input())
for n in range( 0,n,1):
Print (“*”)
```

Comment: Если вы это не напишите сами, то не поймете, тут принцип работы циклов (на всех языках)

Comment: Да я сижу уже голову час ломаю, хоть подтолкнуть меня(

Comment: Воспользуйтесь дебагером, когда-то он мне помог понять это все, когда я прогнал цикл пошагово. Час это немного, я почти день вложил в свое время.

Comment: Отредактировал, пишу с телефона, так что не удобно

Comment: @vladspirin если человек пришёл на этот сайт за таким вопросом, то он априори не хочет научиться програмировать :) поэтому зачем ему мучаться)

Comment: @Evgeny а коль вы понимаете, что человек только учится, лучше распишите пошагово что делает цикл на разных итерациях, так человек усвоит это навсегда и от вашего ответа будет толк на долгие годы.

Answer (score 3):

Во первых, вы видите, что картина *симметричная* - пусть будем сначала заниматься только её левой частью.

В *первой* строке *одна* звёздочка, во *второй* - *две*, в *третьей* - *три*, и т.д. Значит, *количество звёздочек соответствует номеру строки* (`line_no` в последующей программе).

После звёздочек идут *пробелы*. Сколько-же их будет? Столько, *чтобы звёздочек плюс пробелов было всегда то-же самое количество* - скажем, дважды максимального количества звёздочек (т. е. максимального числа строки, которое задал пользователь): `2 * lines`.

Отсюда вытекает, что когда звёздочек в строке `line_no` будет `line_no`, то пробелов будет
`(2 * lines - line_no)`.

Когда мы хотим сделать строку из одинаковых символов, например `"AAA"` пишем `3 * "A"`. Подобным образом с каким-нибудь другим символом - в нашем случае со звёздочкой и пробелом.

Это значит, что первая половина строки будет `line_no * "*" + (2 * lines - line_no) * " "`.
Ну и вторая - симметричная половина - наоборот.

А теперь программа:

```
lines = int(input("Количество строк: "))

for line_no in range(1, lines + 1):
    left_part  = line_no * "*" + (2 * lines - line_no) * " "
    right_part = (2 * lines - line_no) * " " + line_no * "*"
    print(left_part + right_part)
```

Цикл `for line_no in range(1, lines + 1):` значит, что переменная `line_no` будет постепенно принимать значение от `1` (включительно) до `lines + 1` (исвключительно, т.е. только до `lines`, что мы хотим).

Comment: +1  за подробное разъяснение, думаю этот ответ будет полезен всем, кто ищет подобное. К этому вопросу и будем дубликатить.

Comment: Спасибо, @VladSpirin. :-)

Answer (score -1):

Вот вам пример решения, чтобы уяснить логику:

```
gap = 20 # ширина строки целиком
for i in range(1,6): # ange(1,6) - итого 5 - количество строк
    print('*'*i+' '*(gap-i*2)+'*'*i) # печать необходимого количества звезд слева,
                                     # необходимого количества пробелов, необходимого 
                                     # количества звезд справа - всё в зависимости
                                     # от номера текущей строки (i).
```

На выходе:

```
*                  *
**                **
***              ***
****            ****
*****          *****
```